# issue in gridview[checkbox and images]

Tags: asp.net

'  />
                    
                
                 
                    
                        '/>

this is my code where i am trying to display checkbox and images
 my table has columns

```
itemID  Imagespath
1       item1.jpg
2       item2.jpg
3       item3.jpg
4       item4.jpg
```

but in output it is showing as  i want to show only checkbox and image

but now it is showing  checkbox along with the [ID i.e 1 ,2,3 etc ]  which i  should make as  [ID as invisiable  in  design  but  in code behind i should be able to get the selected value ID]

is there ant way i can remove the  gridview  border and  row border.
 **actually i am trying to amke a  checkboxlist alaong with the images,** right now even images are not getting displayed

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage the GridView's DataKeys property for this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvImages" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CustomerID">
```

In your code you can loop through the rows and read the data key for that row and get the checkbox like this:

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvImages.Rows)
{
    int CustomerID = (int)gvImages.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Value;
    CheckBox CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("CheckBox1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Text property of Checkboxes not used for server side value. Checkboxes don't have a value property. They have only Checked property for value.

In your case you should add an hidden field in your row that will hold the value of ID column, and you can get it at server side.